# VIM 7.2 Scripting problem with `:perldo` and multiple expressions

Tags: perl, vim, scripting

## Background task

To eliminate X-Y problems I'll say what I'm doing: I'm trying to use `:perldo` in VIM 7.2 to complete two tasks:

- Clear all trailing whitespace, including (clearing not deleting) lines that *only* have whitespace

  - `s/\s+$//;`
- Remove non-tab whitespace that exists before the first-non space character

  - `s/^ (\s*) (?=\S) / s#[^\t]##g;$_ /xe;`

I'd like to do this all with one pass. Currently, using `:perldo`, I can get this working with two passes. (by using :perldo twice)

The command should look like this:

```
:perldo s/\s+$//; s/^ (\s*) (?=\S) / s#[^\t]##g;$_ /xe;
```

## Perl background

In order to understand this problem you must know a little bit about Perl `s///` automagically binds to the default variable `$_` which the regex is free to modify. Most core functions operate on `$_` by default.

`perl -e'$_="foo"; s/foo/bar/; s/bar/baz/; print'` # will print `baz`

The assumption is that you can chain expressions using `:perldo` in VIM and that it will work logically.

## VIM not being nice

Now my VIM problem is better demonstrated with code -- I've reduced it to a simple test. Open a new buffer place the following text into it:

```
aa bb
aa
bb
```

Now run this `:perldo s/a/z/; s/b/z/;` The buffer now has:

```
za zb
aa
zb
```

Why was the first regex unsuccessful on the second row, and yet the second regex was successful by itself, and on the first row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the whole Perl expression you pass to `:perldo` must return a true / defined value, or the results are discarded, per-line.

Try this, nothing happens on any line:

```
:perldo s/a/z/; s/b/z/; 0
```

Try this, it works on all 3 lines as expected:

```
:perldo s/a/z/; s/b/z; 1
```

An example in the `:perldo` documentation hints at this:

```
:perldo $_ = reverse($_);1
```

but unfortunately it doesn't say explicitly what's going on.

Comment: Yep, that'd explain the OP's results: The last statement in the `perldo` must return a true value, or the entire result of `perldo` is discarded.

Comment: I've switched this to my answer, because it makes sense. I imagine the other answer was exploiting that `0 + 0 = 0 ( no replacement )`, and 1+0 or 0+1 would result in a replacement. This is a pretty silly thing to not have documented.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know what `:perldo` is doing exactly, but if you run something like

```
:perldo s/a/z/+s/b/z/
```

then you get something more like you'd expect.

Comment: I still don't know how it works, but I suspected it would behave better with a single expression.

Comment: should probably be added to `:he`

Comment: rule he was adding these in scalar context. So the amount of matches in the first `s///` plus the amount of matches in the second `s///` is the return code. The second `s` failing can not negate the return code of the first `s///`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like only the last command is run on all lines in [range].